# Getting co ordinates of grid points in a plot

Tags: plotting

I have this density plot defined as

```
plot=DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + 
      y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[
      2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Which produces a plot

[image]

Now what I would like to do is make gridlines and then get the co ordinates of points where the grid lines intersect. I have done a drawing of this shown here
[image]

What I would like is to get the co ordinates of the red points.

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: You might be interested in [`GridLines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html).

Comment: I don't really understand what is the connection between your plot and the grid points. To generate the list of gridpoints, you can use ``Table``, such as: ``gridpoints = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -3, 3, 1}, {y, -3, 3, 1}], 1]``. If you want to show these points on the plot, use ``Show[plot, ListPlot[gridpoints]]``. If you want to evaluate your function at these gridpoints, define your function ``f[x_, y_] := (E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2`` and evaluate with ``f @@@ gridpoints``.

Comment: Or `gridcoords = Tuples[{xCoordList, yCoordList}]`. -- I don't understand how the grid lines are to be generated. Do you have something in mind, or are you going to accept whatever some @userRandom suggests?